# LXPanel reconfigures itself after restart

Tags: lxde, lubuntu

My current configuration for lxpanel.

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
  edge=right
  monitor=1
  height=50
  align=top
  width=106
  transparent=1
  background=0
  tintcolor=#000000
  alpha=0
  usefontcolor=0
  iconsize=16
  widthtype=pixel
}
Plugin {
  type=thermal
  Config {
    NormalColor=#00ff00
    Warning1Color=#00ff00
    Warning2Color=#00ff00
    AutomaticLevels=1
    Warning1Temp=98
    Warning2Temp=103
    AutomaticSensor=1
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=cpu
  Config {
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=monitors
  Config {
    DisplayCPU=0
    DisplayRAM=1
    RAMColor=#00ff00
  }
}
```

After I do a `lxpanelctl restart` configuration from the file does not change but when I right click and view the properties it shows that width is 150. If I change the width value to 50 and press enter the `lxpanel` resizes and everything works fine until the panel is restarted.

How to overcome the fact that `lxpanel` is adjusting its width automatically.

I have tried with only a clock icon, that also causes the same affect.
I have tried to look for logs but have not found any
I am running Lubuntu 15.10

Thanks